# If I do not close the file in C

Tags: c, fclose

Let's say we have a c program as follow:

```
int fun(char *path) {
    FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");
    int result;
    // Do something here without closing the file
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = fun(argv[1]);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that it is not a good habit to not close a file. But I wonder when will be file be closed by the OS. When `fun` returns or when `main` returns? How about when the program is killed?

Comment: According to the Standard (C11 §5.1.2.2.3 1), "a return from the initial call to the **main** function is equivalent to calling the **exit** function....", which closes all open streams. As for "how about when the program is killed?", that sounds like it would depend on the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `main`. File handles are allocated to the process, not any given function. Think of what would happen if you declared `f` as a global variable. Any process termination will close files and free any other system resources associated to the process.

Comment: It would not crash the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, OS will reclaim the file descriptor which is open after program completes execution. However, if your program is a daemon then it will keep opening files causing OS to reach the limit of FS_OPEN_MAX. You can see this with the command `ulimit -a` along with other limits.

This is specific to Unix or GNU/Linux for Windows I do not know.

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63179
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63179
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: You can exceed the number of open files on any process, not just a daemon.

Comment: Yes I know that. There are two ways. One through ulimit and another through sysfs or sysctl configuration files. But that was not asked for.